# Changing RadCombobox Font Color when Disabled in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, javascript, telerik

I am not exactly sure why this is not as easy as I expected. I need to change the font color of a disabled RadCombobox control .  Any idea how I can do this please?

.RadComboBoxcss
{
    background-color: #808080;
    color:Blue;
    font-weight:bold;
}

Comment: How are you disabling the radcombobox?  On the server or on the client?

Comment: Enabled property is set to false in the declaration itself. Only I also want to change the font color as well but problem is that does not seem to take.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try modifying the preset CSS selector for the RadComboBox.  Take a look [here](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/combo_appearancecssselectors.html).

It seems like the following should do the trick:

```
.rcbDisabled  { background-color: #808080; color:Blue; font-weight:bold; }
```

Comment: I wasn't able to get that working please. Where do I modify this? What I did was add this directly in my page and that did not work. I also modified the site css document and that did not work. any ideas where this ought to go?

Comment: <telerik:RadComboBox ID="rcpos" ForeColor="Yellow" BackColor="blue" runat="server" Width="200" Enabled="false">

</telerik:RadComboBox>

Comment: What are you putting inside the <ItemTemplate> of the ComboBox